# How to use public static function localDate?

Tags: php, datetime, datepicker, datetimepicker, datetime-format

**Subject: Gregorian calendar to Persian calendar**

I've a function which is in below to get current date in **I18n.php**:

```
  public static function localDate($date = "")
  {
    $local = "";
    switch (strlen($date))
    {
    default:
    $local = $date;
    break;
    }
    return $local;
  }
```

***For example: Above code output format is like this:  2015-10-26***

In this function, **$local = $date;**  it will get current date and it will show it on page.

Now I'm gonna change **$local** and **$date;** to **new date**, I mean different time zone and date. 
I'm gonna add this following function into above code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/jdatetime.class.php';
$date = new jDateTime(true, true, 'Asia/Tehran');
echo $date->date("l j F Y");
?>
```

and above code output date format is like this, you can [check it here out](http://clinichoma.com/test/datetest/datetest.php)

here is also [jdatetime.class.php](https://github.com/sallar/jDateTime/blob/master/jdatetime.class.php)

How can I change my current date to this new date based on my code ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To simplify a little, I've just used the static version of jDateTime. The `header` call doesn't really belong in the function, this should be used at the start of the code that actually does the output.

```
public static function localDate($date = "")
{
    $local = "";
    switch (strlen($date))
    {
        default:
            require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/jdatetime.class.php';
            $local = jDateTime::date("l j F Y", strtotime($date), true, true, 'Asia/Tehran');
            break;
    }
    return $local;
}
```

An example usage (assuming the function is in a class called `Formatter`:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

echo Formatter::localDate('2015-10-26');
```

If you are using jDateTime elsewhere in your project, you could move the `require_once` somewhere more central.

Comment: You are amazing man, It's working like charm! :) Thank you so much bro.. :)   Just I've a question maybe you know how to solve it, The current date is already solved. but I'm facing a problem about Patient Age.. for example:  If DOB is 2000 and current year is 2015 so Patient age is 15 Yrs old, but if we will enter patient age based on Persian calendar, for example 1350 then it will show patient age 665 yrs old, I mean 2015 - 1350 = 665 , so how to changed current year to Persian calendar based on jDateTime ??? Is it possible or not ??

Comment: No worries! You should probably open a new question if you have a different question, but you should be able to get the current year in Persian calendar like this: `jDateTime::date("Y", false, false, true, 'Asia/Tehran');`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Actually still the problem is exist, I've posted complete code before but  no one could answer it, but you could! :) again thanks for your help, is it possible for you to have a look to this, case 8 is related about age, and birthday format, thanks again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33327955/how-to-change-default-date-in-php-to-another-calendar-date